# Java birthday paradox algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I've made a small implementation of the famous birthday paradox, trying to find a collision between two random birthdates (here integer between 1 and 365) for the first time.
But it returns always a value around let's say 40 and 70, which does not fit the stats at all.
Is something wrong with my algo, or with the random int generator, both ? Thanks for your feedback.

Here is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] birthday = new int[200];

    for(int i = 0; i<20;i++){
        Collision(birthday); 
    }
}

public static int Collision(int birthday[]){
    Random rand = new Random();  
    for(int i = 1; i<birthday.length;i++){        
        birthday[i] = rand.nextInt(365);
    }

    int count = 0;        
    for(int i = 0; i<birthday.length; i++){          
        for(int j= i+1 ; j<birthday.length; j++){            
            if (birthday[i] == birthday[j]){               
                count++;
            }            
        }          
    }

    System.out.print(count+" ");        
    return count;  
}
```

Here is the output for ex :

> 45 50 60 52 53 53 50 49 37 68 52 53 51 43 49 51 46 43 45 35

Comment: what's the expected average output?

Comment: For a set of 200 people, a collision count of between 40 and 70 sounds reasonable.

Comment: So what do you expect? The chances of collision is almost 100% and you found on average 40. It does not contradict theory see [birhtday problem calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=birthday+problem+calculator&rawformassumption={%22F%22,+%22BirthdayProblem%22,+%22n%22}+-%3E%22200%22&rawformassumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+{{%22BirthdayProblem%22}}&rawformassumption={%22MC%22,%22%22}-%3E{%22Formula%22})

Comment: Thanks for your replies. According to the theory, the probability is 50% for a set of 23 people, which I never have...SP there should be some flaws somewhere. I would expect sometimes 25 or 15 or even less...

Comment: Doing the sums, the expected value should indeed be slightly higher, around 84.

Comment: @loukios You always test with 200 people, where the probability of at least one collision is practically 1. But you're counting the number of collisions, the expected number of which can be calculated like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/birthday-problem-expected-number-of-collisions). According to this, the numbers you get are lower than they should.

Comment: Yep, you're counting the number of people that have a birthday in common with someone after them in the array, regardless of what day it is.  If what you're trying to do is find how many people it takes before there is a collision you break out of `i` and `j` loops(may need a boolean variable) when things are equal and return `j`, or use @Radoh's solution.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:
What you essentially did in your algorithm is that you generated 200 random birthdays and counted how many collisions exist among them.

---

You know you could make things a lot simpler by using a `Set`, which is empty at the beginning. Then in a simple while loop generate birthdays (numbers up to 365), try adding them in the `Set`, and the first time you get a collision - the number is already in the `Set` - you have your answer (the answer being the size of the Set).

That is, if your goal really is to find a collision in minimum number of birthdays.

E.g., this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int t = 0; t < 20; t++)
{
    Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
    while (true)
    {
        int n = rand.nextInt(365);
        if (!b.add(n))
            break;
    }
    System.out.print(b.size() + " ");
}
```

Produces:

```
15 30 24 4 8 19 10 40 32 31 30 14 41 30 15 7 15 52 24 27
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Java so I was not aware of it, but I'll try.

Comment: You can even simplify it to `if (!b.add(n)) break;`

Comment: @biziclop Ahh, nice, I always forget that `Set.add()` returns boolean :)

Comment: Even more concise, use `while (b.add(rand.nextInt(365))) ;`.  No need for temporary var `n`.

Comment: @pjs nice, but I'll leave it as it is, for clarity's sake, since loukios said he's new to Java.

Answer (score 3):

Your numbers look fairly reasonable.

But you are repeatedly instantiating a new `Random` instance. That ruins the generator's statistical properties. Do it once at the beginning of your program.

(Eventually you'll need to consider February 29th too but that's very much a second-order effect).

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems OK and the results are reasonable.

FYI you could use streams to very efficiently do all the heavy lifting in 1 line:

```
private static Random rand = new Random(); 
public static int collision(int size) {
    return size - Stream.generate(() -> rand.nextInt(365)).limit(size).distinct().count();
}
```

And a 1-line main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Stream.of(200).map(MyClass::collision).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```